# Nodemon doesn't restart

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon, docker-machine

I have a nodemon running in a docker-container with a mounted volume on OSX. Nodemon is receiving the file-change but it doesn't restart the server.

Output:

```
Creating piclet_web_1...
Attaching to piclet_web_1
web_1 | 7 Sep 13:37:19 - [nodemon] v1.4.1
web_1 | 7 Sep 13:37:19 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
web_1 | 7 Sep 13:37:19 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
web_1 | 7 Sep 13:37:19 - [nodemon] starting node ./index.js
web_1 | restify listening at http://[::]:80 //normal output of started node-app
//file-change, which gets detected
web_1 | 7 Sep 13:37:30 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
//no output of restarted server
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:0.12.7-wheezy
EXPOSE 80

RUN npm install nodemon -g

ADD app /app
WORKDIR app

RUN npm install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./app/lib:/app/lib
  links:
    - db
  command: "nodemon -L ./index.js"
db:
  image: mongo:3.1.7
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some context like a `Dockerfile` for the application and the `docker-compose.yml` so people can test the issue? I'm sure you've also read https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/419?

Comment: I edited the question. I've indeed read this issue, but it refers to a problem that the changes is not detected, my problem is that the change IS detected, but the node-app isn't restarted (no startup-output on the console and old version still available).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by choosing another base-image for the container: `node:0.12.7` instead of `node:0.12.7-wheezy`